# Read CSV from list of files and "mutate" a column (date)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Trying to read in a number of CSV files and then summarise up to a useful level, but the issue is that some of the dates are YYYYMMDD (character) and others are DD-MM-YYYY (date) so the summarise function summarises these separately.  I've tried the mutate function (my code is below) but it results in `no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"`.

I've also played around with the map function in purrr but I'm not familiar with it and can't get that to work either.

```
sales_files <- list.files(path = "*folder redacted*", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  mutate(date = case_when(left(date,4) == "2020" ~ as.Date(as.character(date),format="%Y%m%d"), TRUE ~ date))
  group_by(`ID`, `Date`) %>% 
  summarise(sales = sum(`Value`), quantity = sum(`Qty`)) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

output <- list.files(path = "*folder redacted*", full.names = TRUE) %>%
             map_df(~{
               #Read file name
               read_csv(.x) %>%
               #Convert different format date 
               mutate(date = parse_date_time(date, orders = c('Ymd', 'dmY'))) %>%
               #Group by ID and Date
               group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
               #Sum Value and Qty
               summarise(sales = sum(Value), quantity = sum(Qty))
           })
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for me, I just had to make one minor change to c('Ymd dmY') by adding a comma: c('Ymd', 'dmY').  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime` to parse multiple dates automatically

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(anytime)
library(readr)
output <- list.files(path = "*folder redacted*", full.names = TRUE) %>%
             map_df(~{               
               read_csv(.x) %>%              
               mutate(date = anydate(date)) %>%               
               group_by(ID, Date) %>%                
               summarise(sales = sum(Value), quantity = sum(Qty))
           })
```